# Jquery - waypoints - animate nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

**Here is my idea:**

- List item a black border that follow scroll on nav
- List item

scroll to a `<div>` on click

it's hard to explain (I'm french) so just try it on:
http://mathieualbore.com/traci/

It work when you click from smilio > skiply but not working if start from skiply and click > smilio

the code :

```
$("#smilio").waypoint({
    handler: function(event, direction) {   
    left = $('.menu li[data-target="#smilio"]').position().left;
    w = $('.menu li[data-target="#smilio"] span').width();
    $('.active').stop().animate({ left: left, width: w+40 })    
},
offset: 40
});

$("#skiply").waypoint({
    handler: 
    function(event, direction) {
    left = $('.menu li[data-target="#skiply"]').position().left;
    w = $('.menu li[data-target="#skiply"] span').width();
    $('.active').stop().animate({ left: left, width: w+40 })
},
offset: 40
});
```

and

```
$(".menu li").click(function() {
 var target = $(this).data("target");
 var scrollY = $(target).position().top;
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrollY-40 }, 500);
}
```

Comment: I find a way to do the trick :

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to do the trick if someone is interested

```
$(".menu li, a").click(function() {
var target = $(this).data("target");
var scrollY = $(target).position().top;
$("html, body").animate({ 

scrollTop: scrollY-40

}, 500, function() {

left = $('.menu li[data-target="'+target+'"]').position().left;
w = $('.menu li[data-target="'+target+'"]').width();    
$('.active').stop().animate({
    left: left,
    width: w+40
})

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And this to simplify waypoints :

```
$(".menu li").each(function() {
var target = $(this).data("target");

$(target).waypoint({
    handler: function(event, direction) {   
    left = $('.menu li[data-target="'+target+'"]').position().left;
    w = $('.menu li[data-target="'+target+'"]').width();
    $('.active').stop().animate({ left: left, width: w+40 })
    },

    offset: 40

  });

  });
```